# How can we change the width of PopupMenu, and center the text?

Tags: android, styles, width, popupmenu

I'm having a hard time in android studio. 
I want the width changed to match the text size in PopupMenu, and the text to be centered.

In activity, PopupMenu used :

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(PatientListActivity.this, R.style.YOURSTYLE);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, typeView);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_type, popupMenu.getMenu());
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
```

And my PopupMenu's menu item is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/item_all"
    android:title="All"/>
<item android:id="@+id/item_p"
    android:title="P"/>
<item android:id="@+id/item_et"
    android:title="ET"/>
<item android:id="@+id/item_no"
    android:title="ㅡ"/>
</menu>
```

I specified PopupMenu's style like this, but nothing changed.

```
<style name="YOURSTYLE" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

I hope that the width size in PopupMenu can be changed, and the text can be arranged in the center.